# Reliable budget small diesel car - around 4-7 years old

Tags: diesel, small-engine

I'm looking to buy a small budget diesel car in the UK I was wondering what are some reliable suggestions.

I have a D4D Yaris at the moment that is playing up. I have been looking at the Hyundai I20, Mazda 2 and Skoda Fabia 1.6. Any of these any good in that price range?

Average annual drive - around 14,000 miles
Usual weekday commute of 10 miles with summer 1-2 weekday outdoor sport trips of 100 miles per week. Remaining trips during the weekend (mainly around 400 miles round trip but varies - weather dependant)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided much detail on the market you are in, nor what your requirements are.

I might try to advise you, but I am biased, currently owning about 5 VW diesels of various vintages.  The daily driver I have is a '99 and I paid $3300US for it four years ago.  While the VW diesel market is a bit unstable in the US, a 2005 to 2007 model year Jetta diesel might fit your budget.

However, to really answer your question usefully, one needs to know where you are located, and what your requirements for the vehicle are, other than simply fuel type.

Comment: I have a 2006 Yaris and it has rusted quite badly due to the salt on the roads and the sea. (Scotland)